# Network Security for MAC-OS X

Tags: security, macos, network-monitoring

I have a new set up for software development for iOS devices. I am using MACs for the development and the company may grow from three employees right now to 20 in near future. I want to make the MACs secure so that the client code is safe and does not leave office.

Few ways I can think of a notorious employee trying to do that is

1. Get it on USB-key/External-Disk
2. Burn it on CD/DVD
3. Transfer it to a bluetooth device
4. Transfer it to Infra-Red Device
5. Email it as an attachment
6. Upload it to Dropbox or any such service
7. FTP to a remote server

To handle this one by one I need to do following

1. Disable USB access to user accounts (only admin allowed to insert a new device). But often times we need to stick in iphone/ipod touch to do on-device testing. How can I restrict the devices or get notified when someone tried to put a foreign device in any of the USB slots?
2. Disable CD/DVD write functions except for admin. Can I do this?
3. Disable bluetooth access. And if someone tries to pair a device, can I get notified or maitain a log?
4. Wireless keyboard and mouse use Infra-Red (IR) technology. How can I limit these devices?
5. Need to block all outgoing emails except company emails. Can I keep a tab on all outgoing traffic (may be by file size) so that I know some one is trying to up-load a file?
6. Again disable access to such website. But then every 15 days a new service springs up. How do I tackle this?
7. Disable ftp outgoing services. Can I do this?

Importantly is there a monitoring software that will allow me to do this? I don't mind paying. But since this is a start-up I cannot spend a fortune on this. And of-course I prefer open source solutions for the control it gives me to extend and scratch my specialized itch :)

Finally I hope I wont be judged as a bad boss or something. I am all for developer freedom but we are into consulting business and protecting client code takes priority.

Thanks for your time and looking forward to your help.
Dev.

Comment: Someone could easily run an SSH server on port 443, which is the port commonly used by HTTPS.  You can transfer files over SSH, which is an encrypted protocol.  Do you plan on disabling HTTPS company-wide?

Comment: I dont know if I should add this to the list or just assume, if he can figure that out, probably he is smart enough that he does not need to  steal iphone app code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't trust your developer not to run off with your source code, don't hire them.  They can find a way around your "solution"

If you can't trust any developers to not steal your source code, work alone.  Anything known by two people is no longer a secret.

Comment: I totally agree to this philosophy Steven ... I wish I could work like this, However one thing I have learnt while starting a business is that it may not always work out the way you thought it might :) ... Just want to do whatever I can from my side and then leave the rest to fate (the part that is not under my control). But I so wish I could find such people whom I can trust and are good developers at the same time :)

Comment: I would not work at a company that put in place these measures... I presume a lot of good devs won't either.  You're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: I think I will have to go with this for an answer :)